# What goes in the username and password fields for PHPMailer?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, web-development-server

I'm trying to make one of those commonly known contact forms for a website, so that the user can directly send me an email from my website.

Here is the code I have so far

```html
<html>


<body>


<?php
require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';


$mail->Username = "username@example.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

//$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails

$mail->From = "vikxsrk@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "FROM NAME";

$mail->addAddress("vik.kalkat@gmail.com","Vik Kalkat");

$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";

?>


</body>


</html>
```

The error I am getting is

```html
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent 
PHPMailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

I'm guessing this may be because my "Username" and "Password" parameters might be wrong since I'm unsure what username and password is suppose to go here.
Is it the login information for the email account to which I want the emails to be sent to?

Comment: try `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` to see more error output, it's often an ssl problem

Comment: i got..

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent 
PHPMailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: have you tried TLS on port 587 instead of SSL on 465?  the username and password have to be your google account

Comment: by the way, this is REALLY common and there are a bazillion versions of this question on here.  did you search?

Comment: yea I saw googled alot and tried a TON of different things because I cant solve this dam issue.

Comment: I can't help but notice that this says localhost in the comments.  Have you tried putting it in your server environment yet?  Because they are usually configured to work and a lot of people have problem doing it locally.  Put it up in a test area on your site and you might be fine

Comment: Haven't tried that. I'll try it now and let you know. A huge thanks for your help btw

Comment: didnt work. 
Internal server error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your google account and open the security option on the left side. After that scroll down the page and look for option **Allow the less secure app** and turn that option on.

Try again by refreshing your page and this time you will be able to send the Email using Gmail. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks man, any idea if there will be support to "secure enabled" for GMail, went through to tons of sites looking for the answer to find out it was on the account side

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the TLS one

which is on port 587.

Change

```
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

to

```
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

another issue might be that your Mailer is 'smtp' instead of 'mail'

Answer (score 0):

Please change your port number from 465 to 587.
and if you are use SMTP mailer then change SMTPSecure from ssl to tls.

Comment: the same answer has been given before. Please upvote if you think it's correct.